# "device or resource busy" error when trying to push image with docker

Tags: docker

When pushing to the official registry, I get the following error:

> Failed to generate layer archive: Error mounting '/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-399203-ed78b67d527d993117331d27627fd622ffb874dc2b439037fb120a45cd3cb9be' on '/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/ed78b67d527d993117331d27627fd622ffb874dc2b439037fb120a45cd3cb9be': device or resource busy

The first time I tried to push the image, I ran out of memory on my hard drive. After that I cleaned up and should have now enough space to push it, but the first try somehow locked the image. **How can I free it again?**

- I have stopped and removed the container running the image, but that didn't help.
- I have restarted the docker service, without any results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it might be related to the issue mentioned here: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4767

It sounds like you've tried stopping and removing the container.  Have you tried restarting the docker daemon and/or restarting the host?

Comment: redeploying the image (working on AWS) solved the issue afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I changed `docker-compose.yml` volume section and gave mysql volumes new name like:

```
volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql_new
        - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

then start docker container and everything works fine.

```
docker-compose up -d --build mysql
```