# Pushing to docker registry fails: Error mounting /dev/mapper/...: device or resource busy

Tags: docker

I'm trying to push a docker image to my own registry server, but fail to do so on lxc-docker `1.7.1`, Ubuntu `14.04`, Linux kernel `3.17.1-vanilla-3.17-for-dp-mst`:

```
The push refers to a repository [example.org:5001/example/name] (len: 1)
45615d5b6520: Image already exists 
d660ae18c164: Image already exists 
ce175a447fba: Image already exists 
3bfbc78d8ab0: Image already exists 
ff51cac082ac: Buffering to Disk 
Error pushing to registry: Error mounting
 '/dev/mapper/docker-252:1-2885400-d3010c1febd33ebba400a593df550db2064cf16541d3970fb93bb524ee6056b4'
 on '/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/d3010c1febd33ebba400a593df550db2064cf16541d3970fb93bb524ee6056b4':
 device or resource busy
```

What can I do to fix this?

Restarting the docker daemon did not help.
I also had to set `--storage-opt='dm.blocksize=64k'` as docker daemon start option; otherwise it would not start up at all.

---

This sounds a bit like  ["device or resource busy" error when trying to push image with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22765576/282601), but that is an error about generating a layered archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting with a new kernel (`3.19.0-22`) and the matching -extras package made it work.